# doubts on javascript apply - function memoization

Tags: javascript, memoization

I'm struggling with an example of js memoization found on a book, here's the code:

```
Function.prototype.memoized = function(key){
    this._values = this._values || {};
    return this._values[key] !== undefined ? this._values[key] : this._values[key] = this.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

here's a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/stJz3/) with a complete example

what I don't really get is how this piece of code works and what it does, in particular the `apply` part:

```
return this._values[key] !== undefined ? this._values[key] : this._values[key] = this.apply(this, arguments);
```

I know and understand how `apply` works

> The apply() method calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided as an array

suppose that `this._values[key]` is equal to `undefined`, then the returned value will be `this.apply(this, arguments)`: does this code re-launch the `memoized` function? I've tried to add some logs inside the function to see how many times the function is called, but it seems it's been launched only once..

Can anyone please give me a hint? It's probably a dummy question, please be patient, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use a simple example, fibonacci numbers.

```
function fib(n) {
    if (n < 2) return 1;
    return fib.memoized(n-1) + fib.memoized(n-2);
}
```

Here we can see that the `memoized` method is applied on the `fib` function, i.e. your [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) refers to the `fib` function. It does not relaunch the `memoized` function, but "launches" the function on which it was called. However, it does call it with `this` set to the function itself, which does not make any sense. Better:

```
Function.prototype.memoized = function(key){
    if (!this._values)
        this._values = {};
    if (key in this._values)
        return this._values[key];
    else
        return this._values[key] = this.apply(null, arguments);
// pass null here:                            ^^^^
}
```

Even better would be if `memoized` would return a closure:

```
Function.prototype.memoized = function(v) {
    var fn = this, // the function on which "memoized" was called
        values = v || {};
    return function(key) {
        if (key in values)
            return values[key];
        else
            return values[key] = fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}
var fib = function(n) {
    if (n < 2) return 1;
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}.memoized();
// or even
var fib = function(n) { return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) }.memoized({0:1, 1:1});
```

Comment: thanks, you're a real *javascript ninja*, IYKWIM. I thin I got it now: when I call `isPrime.memoized(5)` actually I'm not calling `isPrime()` (I totally missed it!), I'm calling `isPrime` `memoized()` function: the function checks whether if the key has already been processed in the past. If so, return the already processed result, otherwise launch `isPrime(5)` (as you pointed out `this` in `this.apply(...)` is the calling function context, in other words `isPrime`), store the value in cache and return the value. is this correct?

Comment: @thefourtheye and bergi thank you both for the clean explaination

Answer (score 1):

**Notes**

1. Since you are attaching `memoized` to the `Function.prototype`, you can invoke this `memoized` on some other function only. Like in your example

   ```
   isPrime.memoized(5)
   ```
2. Since you are invoking `memoized` on a function, the `this` will be referring to the function on which the `memoized` is invoked. So, in this case, `this` refers to `isPrime`.

---

**Actual explanation**

```
this._values = this._values || {};
```

This line makes sure that the `isPrime` has got an attribute with the name `_values` and it should have an empty object, if it is not there already.

```
this._values[key] !== undefined
```

This check is to make sure that we have been already called with `key` or not. If the value is not `undefined`, then return `this._values[key]`.

Otherwise,

```
this._values[key] = this.apply(this, arguments)
```

store the result of calling `this.apply(this, arguments)` in `this._values[key]` and return it. Now the important part.

```
this.apply(this, arguments)
```

It is straight forward. `arguments` is an array like object. So, If you have actually called `isPrime` like this `isPrime(1, 2, 3, 4)`, arguments will have `{'0': 1, '1': 2, '2': 3, '3': 4}`. Now that we are inside `memoized`, we need to invoke `isPrime` as it was intended to be invoked. So, `this.apply(this, arguments)` is done. `Function.prototype.apply`, tries to spread the array like object passed as the second parameter, while invoking the function.