# Why need apply in memoization function?

Tags: javascript, memoization

I've been toyin with concept of memoization and there are obviously different implementations of it. I put this together and it seems to work fine:

```
Function.prototype.memoized = function(a) {
    debugger
    if (typeof cache === "undefined") cache = [];
    if (cache[a]) {
        return cache[a];
    } else {
        cache[a] = this(a);
        return cache[a];
    }
}

Function.prototype.memoize=function() {
  t=this;
  return function() {
   // Resig seems to use this:
   return t.memoized.apply(t,arguments);
   // why not simple this:
   //return t.memoized(arguments[0]);
  }

}

myTest = (function fibonacci(n) {

    return n < 2 ? n : fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}).memoize();

console.log(myTest(2));
```

My question is however why in some implementations I see 
   `return t.memoized.apply(t,arguments);` rather than simple `return t.memoized(arguments[0]);` inside of `proptotype.memoize`? I cannot see any advantage apart from passing multiple arguments which are not used anyway. I there any advantage to `apply`?

**EDIT:**

Updated the code and I believe this takes care of major problems so cache as global on window (what was I thinking??) and recursive fibonacci not memoizing calls to itself. Are there any other major issue with my implementation?

```
Function.prototype.memoized = function(a) {

    if (typeof this.cache === "undefined")  this.cache = [];
    if (this.cache[a]) {
        return this.cache[a];
    } else {
        this.cache[a] = this(a);
        return this.cache[a];
    }
}

Function.prototype.memoize=function() {
  t=this;
  return function() {
   //return t.memoized.apply(t,arguments);
   return t.memoized(arguments[0]);
  }

}

myTest = (function fibonacci(n) {
    //return a * 3;

    return n < 2 ? n : fibonacci.memoized(n - 1) + fibonacci.memoized(n - 2);
}).memoize();

console.log(myTest(2));
```

BTW this is learning experience for me and doing it purely for fun, it's not assignment or anything like that uni related.

Comment: use `window["cache"] === undefined` instead of `typeof`

Comment: Using `apply` makes the memoize function more generic. So any number of arguments can be passed to the wrapped function. For example, if you wanted to memoize an add function that could take a variable number of arguments. I don't understand why you would use `t.memoized(arguments[0])` when the generic solution is only slightly more complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, JavaScript functions are [variadic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function), which means that you would need to pay attention to all of them actually. Some `memoize` implementations do this by using `JSON.stringify(arguments)` for the cache key.

---

In this case, it does not make any sense, since the `memoized` method does only use a single argument as well.

However, there are more serious bugs in your code than this little inaccuracy. `cache` is a global variable, while it should be bound to the specific memoized function. Also, your `fib` implementation is [not memoized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22578970/1048572) in the recursive call, where it actually is the most important.

---

The edited version looks good (except for the global `t` variable). In personal, I would have shortened/simplified the code a little bit however:

```
Function.prototype.memoize=function() {
    var t = this;
    this.cache = [];
    return function(a) {
        var cache = t.cache;
        if (typeof cache[a] == "undefined")
            cache[a] = t(a);
        return cache[a];
    };
}

var fibonacci = (function (n) {
    return n < 2 ? n : fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}).memoize();

console.log(fibonacci(2));
```