# What's wrong with my implementation of the memoize function?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, memoization

Theoretically, memoization applied to a referentially transparent like the Fibonacci should speed things up considerably.

```
Function.prototype.memoize = function () {
  var cache = {},
      slice = Array.prototype.slice,
      originalFunction = this;
  return function () {
    var key = slice.call(arguments);
    if (key in cache) {
      return cache[key];
    } else {
      return (cache[key] = originalFunction.apply(this, key));
    }
  };
};

var Y = function (f) {
  return function (x) {
    return f(Y(f))(x);
  };
};

var almostFibonacci = function (f) {
  return function (n) {
    return n == 0 || n == 1 ? n : f(n - 1) + f(n - 2);
  };
};

console.log(Y(almostFibonacci).memoize()(50));
```

The above implementation does not. Computing the **50th** Fibonacci number which ought to be quite doable in case of a memoized version seems impossible in this case. The scratchpad on Firefox keeps dying when I try.

I have a feeling that maybe the closure isn't working. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/x18ewhsu/

Comment: The problem is that only the function that you call is memoized, but not the recursive calls to `f`. Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24642540/1048572), I don't have time for a full answer right now.

Comment: Admittedly, usage of the Y combinator doesn't make it easier to memoize the recursive calls…

Comment: Alright. Looking through the other answer.

Comment: You have to make the Y-combinator itself memoizing (which is actually quite elegant, IMHO). An example can be seen [here](http://matt.might.net/articles/implementation-of-recursive-fixed-point-y-combinator-in-javascript-for-memoization/), using almost the same function as you do. (I'm not posting this as an answer, since it would mostly amount to copying from that article.)

Comment: I've closed this a duplicate of your question from the next day, as I think the answer there covers the topic well and even is specific to your code.