# How can I convert this large factorial function to a higher-order function?

Tags: functional-programming, factorial, higher-order-functions

The following code uses a `cache` object outside of the `factorial` function. The `factorial` function itself is large which has too many concerns of finding factorial and caching.

How can I convert this code to a **higher-order function** and generate the same result when I call

```
console.log(factorial(5));
console.log(factorial(7));
```

```js
cache = { }

function factorial(n) {
  
  if (n === 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  
  if (cache[n])
  {
    return cache[n];
  }
  
  console.log("Stack Up: " + n);
  
  var value = n * factorial(n - 1);
  
  console.log("Stack Down: " + value);
  
  cache[n] = value;
  
  return value;
}

console.log(factorial(5));
console.log(factorial(7));
```

Comment: Such a higher-order function is typically called *memoize* / memoization is a good keyword to google.

Comment: Have a look at [these examples](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22578970/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's already [other answers out there for memoising recursive functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25705254/633183), but I'll adapt that answer to factorial in javascript so you can see how it works more easily

The secret to writing memoised recursive functions is continuation passing style. A similar technique works when you want to make a non-tail recursive function stack-safe.

I'll leave some `console.log` statements in this first example so you can see when it's actually computing and when it's just doing a memo lookup.

```js
const memoise = f => {
  const memo = new Map()
  const compute = (x, k) =>
    (console.log('compute', x),
    memo.get(x, memo.set(x, f(x,k))))
  const lookup = x =>
    (console.log('lookup', x),
    memo.has(x) ? memo.get(x) : compute(x, lookup))
  return lookup
}

const factk = (x, k) => {
  if (x === 0)
    return 1
  else
    return x * k(x - 1)
}

const memfact = memoise(factk)

console.log(memfact(5)) // 120
console.log(memfact(7)) // 5040
```

---

Here I've removed the `console.log` calls inside of `memoise` and instead demonstrate a memoised fibonacci function vs an unmemoised one. Compare the dramatic time difference between `memoise(fibk)` and `badfib`

```js
const memoise = f => {
  const memo = new Map()
  const compute = (x, k) =>
    memo.get(x, memo.set(x, f(x,k)))
  const lookup = x =>
    memo.has(x) ? memo.get(x) : compute(x, lookup)
  return lookup
}

const fibk = (x, k) => {
  if (x < 2)
    return x
  else
    return k(x - 1) + k(x - 2)
}

const badfib = x => {
  if (x < 2)
    return x
  else
    return badfib(x - 1) + badfib(x - 2)
}

console.time('memoised')
console.log(memoise (fibk) (35)) // 9227465 1.46ms
console.timeEnd('memoised')

console.time('unmemoised')
console.log(badfib(35))          // 9227465 135.85ms
console.timeEnd('unmemoised')
```

Comment: We could go further and use partial application - `fibk = k => x => …`

Comment: I'm not seeing where partial application would help this time... Please show me! ^_^

Comment: Maybe it doesn't help a lot, but `const lookup = x => (memo.has(x) ? memo : memo.set(x, comp(x))).get(x); const comp = f(lookup);`